# Firefox 3.6 Ignoring CSS3 border radius

Tags: firefox, css

I am using -moz-border-radius (along with border-bottom-left and the webkit one).

The radius shows up in every browser (that supports css3 radius) no problem.

In firefox, the radius shows up. When I inspect with firebug, radius is missing from the stylesheet (it is there though, just not visible in firebug).

it works [here](http://demo.knarsku.com/insidesign/slider-4.html) on the tabs (first and last tab/li). I am copying that same exact style (css and markup).

Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason why it's not showing up on Firebug is because there's a problem with your syntax. Check the MDC documentation for the correct syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above comment was correct. there was a "-" missing in front of all the webkit and moz styles.

I didn't bother to check because I copied stylesheet directly. How did the -'s get removed? Maybe by visual studios "Format Document" command?